# Is there a good T9 keyboard for Wp7 (Lumia 800) ?

Tags: keyboard

I 'hate' the standard qwerty keyboard on a 'small' touchscreen because it isn't comfortable. I prefer T9. The problem is that actually, T9 external app keyboards are not fully integrated.

Does anyone know why? Or if any exist?

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft does not allow developers to replace the system keyboard, so developers can only create keyboards that are not integrated and cannot be used inside other applications. For example, you can send an email/sms using the separate T9 application, but the T9 keyboard cannot be used in the Microsoft email/sms apps.

I would hazard a guess that one of the reasons Microsoft doesn't allow this is for security. It would be possible for replacement keyboards to log your keystrokes and steal sensitive information e.g. passwords.

Application recommendation question are [off topic](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/faq), but there are a few T9 keyboard available in the [marketplace](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/search?q=t9%20keyboard).